# Loop a table valued function sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, function

I have a table valued function which returns the boss of a person for a given day.

> dbo.Bosses(@empId, @date)

How do I loop through this function with information from another?

I.e, I want to use Table B that has a date and employee Id and I want to use them as arguments to find all the bosses for each day inputted in Table B

```
Table B
EmpId     int
hours     float
day       datetime
creator   int
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming you have SQL Server 2005+

```
SELECT
  *
FROM
  TableB
CROSS APPLY
  dbo.Bosses(TableB.EmpID, TableB.day) AS bosses
```

CROSS APPLY will only return results where the Bosses function returns results.  Similary to an INNER JOIN.

OUTER APPLY will return results for every entry in TableB, similar to a LEFT JOIN.

Answer (score 3):

You need to use `APPLY` operator (`CROSS` or `OUTER`, the former is similar to `INNER JOIN`, the later - to `LEFT JOIN`):

```
SELECT b.*, a.*
FROM table_b b
CROSS APPLY dbo.Bosses(b.emp_id, b.emp_date)a
```